# How to make QDockWidget not to shrink QFrame logo?

Tags: qt4, graphical-logo, qdockwidget

My application has a horizontal top logo that is stretched through all the main window. When I add a QDockWidget it shrinks logo. I want it to be docked under the logo frame. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your logo widget into a QToolBar. QToolBar takes the top side of the window, thus QDockWidget is situaded under it.